# Basic elasticsearch autocomplete

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to set up autocomplete for my elasticsearch cluster. The field I want to use is a text field with journal titles. I tried to use the '[standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester)' completion suggester field type in elasticsearch, but it used too much memory so I had to disable it.

In the meantime I would like to get something basic working, such that someone typing "science" would get a list of suggestions like "science in religion", "science experiments". Then when they type "science in" they would get "science in religion".

I guess this is just a match_phrase query and I can limit it to the top 10 results? Or there is a way to do term frequency across the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can experiment with `match_phrase`, [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html), [prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) over a keyword, and [edge n-grams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) as well. Each of these work well for different use cases.